# (just a quick disclamer that im a complete beginner to programming) I keep getting this syntax error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python

this is the line that has as a syntax error:

```
print("he really liked the name " " + character_name + ", ")
```

its on line 5 btw. I've tried to go back to the course multiple times and checking it over, but my line of code is still the same.

I'm watching a course and I copied exactly what he's doing, what am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Each opening quote needs exactly one closing quote. You've got an extra in there.

Comment: You didn't copy it exactly as you have extra double quotes through all your `print` statements. This one should be `print("he really liked the name " + character_name + ", ")`

Comment: Notice how the syntax highlighting shows this: your `+` characters are all coloured like strings, but your `,` is not. And compare with how the version below is highlighted. That's a nice visual cue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and to programming! Please take a few minutes to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your title isn't very helpful, for example. A good title should concisely summarize your question so other users can decide if they are able to help (or learn), not a disclaimer that you are a new programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Those + signs are string concatenation, they go between strings. So you have 1 too many quotes. It should be

```
print("he really liked the name " + character_name + ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Those + signs are string concatenation, they go between strings. You have one more `"`.

```
print("he really liked the name " + character_name + ",")
```

Or do this:

```
print(f"he really liked the name", character_name, ",")
```

Or use string format

```
print("he really liked the name {0},".format(character_name))
```

Using f strings

```
print("he really liked the name {character_name},")
```

Comment: ok thanks for answering this, it was a big help! however, now im getting another syntax error, this is the line which it says its wrong: print("but he didnt like his age, "  + character_name + "didnt want to be " + character_age +)      i dont know what iim doing wrong, can you help?

Comment: @HnightR Remove the + in the last one.

Comment: @HnightR And make sure the caracter name and the character age is a str.